# How to get all network pc hardware details?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2003

We have a Domain in our company (win xp and 7). We need to get all hardware information (RAM, CPU, HD, ...) and IP of all systems centrally. Is there any software available to do so?

Comment: Vote to close - this is a service or product recommendation. Otherwise the answer is simply "yes". As a pro admin you are supposed to know some google fu - or, as you aer a windows shop, at least being knowledgeable enough to check the MS websites (yes, even they have a product for that). Thera re others, though, including commercial ones.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not a network manager. Our Manager thinks we should go to all of the buildings and check all systems physically! I just tried to be The Smart Worker. My profession is something else, any way Thanks for Your advice.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to answer yes, and not to recommend a product. The capability to do this is already built into Windows, if you're willing to put in the smallest amount of work. You don't need any additional products.  It's called WMI and Powershell Remoting. I'll assume PS 3 or 4 and sufficient domain permissions and network connectivity. This is just a small example of getting hardware details from every machine in the AD domain. You will obviously want to elaborate on this. I'm just giving you the concept:

```
$Creds = Get-Credential
Foreach($computer In Get-ADComputer -Filter *)
{
    If($computer.Name -match [Environment]::MachineName) { Continue }
    [PSCustomObject]@{ 'RAM' = [Math]::Round($(Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName $computer.Name -Credential $Creds).TotalPhysicalMemory / 1GB, 0);
                       'CPU' = $(Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor -ComputerName $computer.Name -Credential $Creds).Name;
                       'CPUMaxSpeed' = $(Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor -ComputerName $computer.Name -Credential $Creds).MaxClockSpeed;
                     }
}
```

Comment: Actually a good advice. Administrators should know scripting, and - in fact - powershell today is administrator baseline. In old times (unix) one would not take an admin serious that can not script. Good advice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are free software for this You can deploy via GPO and it will connect to the server You defined and report all status/hardware etc ...

http://www.fusioninventory.org/

http://www.ocsinventory-ng.org/

I am also sure there are some commercial solutions.

Comment: So what is wrong with my answer ? Any comment ? I dont't agree the answer in simply "yes". If You don't know what are You looking for and how it is called You need a point to start somewhere. Better to recommend open source than being suspected of promoting commercial solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Spiceworks

http://www.spiceworks.com/download/

It will scan any given network and report back with everything you asked for, plus more.

But in the interest of not simply making a product reccomendation, (which is frowned upon here), I will also say that this can be done via powershell, which is my preferred method.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315240.aspx